# Customizing website script disabling it with uBlock Origin and re-injecting it as userscript?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

Is this possible? Let's say there is a portion of the script on a website that is causing "issues". Do you think that preventing the original script from loading, copying its source, editing it and re-injecting it as userscript with tampermonkey will do the trick? I tried doing so but I don't know how to force the loading of the script only on a specific domain.

Maybe I'm asking too much but probably a simple copy and paste of the script with the troublesome part removed won't directly work as I hope, right?

Comment: Be specific. There's many other ways to gracefully patching code.

Comment: This is the script: https://static.vvvvid.it/js/vvvvid.js?v=1.0.7100a (You can use a beautifier for an easier reading of course) and there is a portion of it that manages a built-in anti-adblock alongside other website features. This function is triggering the anti-adblock: https://pastebin.com/KTVHrnXy

Do you think a userscript may help me in some way?

Comment: [AAK](https://reek.github.io/anti-adblock-killer/) is famous for covering such purposes.

Comment: But is AAK capable of disabling only a portion of an external script saving other non-anti-adblock functions? I tried using AAK in the past but it didn't help with that website's script

Comment: Tried re enabling AAK and its userscript but it didn't work. So I'm back here trying to inject this custom userscript instead of the one used by the website..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace Head script using Greasemonkey code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605989/how-to-replace-head-script-using-greasemonkey-code)

Comment: Your theoretic approach is exaclty the way to do it. I've already provided a [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605989/how-to-replace-head-script-using-greasemonkey-code/36649101#36649101) example to a questions with the same issue. No need to post a copy of it here. You might additionally want to utilize [GM_xmlhttpRequest](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) since CORS script source might not be accassible from the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

What I did when I wanted this was to block the script using ad-blocker. [Here's a post how to do that.](https://superuser.com/q/278590/194976)

After that I downloaded the script and changed the part that was causing "issues". After that, I added the script as an userscript.